# How to automatically return to where the cursor was before executing cdo?

Tags: replace, quickfix, navigation

Is it possible to automatically return to where the cursor was before running `:cdo` command?

Currently, the cursor ends in the last file in the quickfix, then I have to navigate back to where I was before running the command.

Comment: Hint: use marks. Feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that pressing `C-o` after the `:cdo` command ends, returns the cursor to its position before running the command. I can now add this `C-o` to the `:cdo` command keybinding.